# Table dosent exist

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error when i try and run some mysql code from a php file on my server :

```
Table 'leaderboard.u' doesn't exist
```

The thing is that the table leaderboard does exist . Its been setup the same way that I have it setup in xampp . It also works on xampp and worked on the server until recently .

What could be causing this ?

EDIT :

```
<?php
include("../../config/connect.php");
if(!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['data']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $_GET['data'];
$key = $_GET['key'];

$result = mysqli_query($connection,"update userbadges set $key='$data' where id='$id'");

if(!$result) {
        echo mysqli_error($connection);
            exit;
}
    echo 'database update ' . mysqli_affected_rows($connection) . ' rows';
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe *leaderboard* this is schema?

Comment: are you sure that database leaderboard has a table with name u?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Thats the thing , the database dosnt have a table called u in it . Iv pasted the code that leads to this error . It dosent try to access a table called u.

Comment: @Drew try the query i posed as solution

Comment: Could you var_dump the variables you are using? Maybe the solutions lies there?

Comment: @RicoHumme  how do i do that?

Comment: var_dump($id); and so on

Comment: @RicoHumme string(1) "2" string(1) "2" string(5) "level"  . Thats what it should be showing

Comment: Could you maybe show the code where you connect to the database? OBS! Remove address/password/username before posting.

Comment: @brannmar that code i no 100% works because I can get information from the database to show on the page.

Comment: So in your output $id = 1, $key = 2 and $data = "level" ?

Comment: nope id = 2 , data = 2 , key = level

Comment: @RicoHumme But this code works on my local xampp install .

Comment: And what are the differences with your local xampp and the remote database ?

Comment: @RicoHumme the only one is that local is windows remote is linux . But the remote database was working a few weeks ago

Comment: Well something should have changed. Does the error you have now occur at your local or remote host? Can you post the config (obscure the username and password and host) of the environment your error is on?

Comment: The error only happens on the remote host . What config shoudl i post?